# Displaying results of a loop

Tags: r

I have created the following loop for reporting the prediction error of polls in 2016.

```
for(i in 1:51){
state.data<-subset(polls, subset=(state==statenames[i]))
latest<-state.data$days_to_election==min(state.data$days_to_election) 
statepred<-(pollp[i,1]<-mean(state.data$Trump[latest])) 
names(statepred)<-statenames[i]
print(statepred)}
```

However, when I knit into a pdf each state is listed one after each other, vertically. How can it get this to display with 6 rows and 10 columns instead?

Answer (score 0):

how about putting it in a vector then making a matrix and then printing it?

`s <- matrix(state_vector), nrow=6)`